# Polymer 3: ReferenceError: define is not defined on Firefox

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I'm manually converting a project from Polymer 2 to Polymer 3.
Note: I first tried the modulizer with no success (I made many attempts in windows, linux and mac) so I decided to go manually. This question is not about modulizer (there are a lot of discussions already).

The project is quite huge so I'm converting it by steps. I have been able to make a basic part working (converting every needed elements into ES6 classes etc).

I'm testing it using polymer serve, so not in a build yet.

It's working correctly in Chrome and Chrome Canary too, and it's loading pretty fast. In Firefox I'm getting a blank page and this error in the console:
ReferenceError: define is not defined

I found nothing about this error in the web so far so I decided to ask the community.

It's stuck in the first line of the loaded element. I'm sorry I cannot provide so much code, it's just to have an idea on where it stucks:

```
define(["../../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js", 
...
...
```

is it correct that the imports of the source code are converted this way in FF?
In this same line there are all the module imports in an array.

The first line of the same element in Chrome console looks like:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from "../../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";
```

and is followed by the other imports, like in the source code that looks like this:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks!

**Update after a few tests:**

I noticed that this issue is happening when I import the module by adding it in a script with createElement.

I tried in a fresh Polymer 3 project (no conversion, just the demo they have in Polymer 3 first element).

If I include the module this way (the default in demo/index.html):

```
<script type="module" src="demo-element.js"></script>
```

it works normally both in Chrome and Firefox.

If I instead include the module this other way:

```
<script>

  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('type','module');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'demo-element.js');
  script.onload = function(){
    console.log('ready');
  };

  document.head.appendChild(script);

</script>
```

it works only in Chrome.
In Firefox it gives the same error (define is not defined):

[image]

I also tried adding a listener to WebComponentsReady and load the module after it:

```
<script>

  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
    console.log('components ready');

    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type','module');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'demo-element.js');
    script.onload = function(){
      console.log('ready');
    };

    document.head.appendChild(script);

  });

</script>
```

and I got in Firefox the same error:

[image]

**Note:** the same issue is happening in Edge too. This is only working in Chrome. I didn't test in Safari.

At this point I'm a bit stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Define a function from RequireJS, in particular, the "define with dependencies" form of that function. It is used to define a "module". If you provide your Polymer 2 version, will be easy to understand the subject. https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure where RequireJS is used in our app. I found that we are only using require.js because it's imported by raven.js for sentry (it's loaded in our preloader as global function). To test I tried to completely remove raven but the error is still there. Do you think it could it be related to Polymer 3 server? Does Polymer use RequireJS itself? 
Also, do you have an idea why it's working in Chrome and not in FF? I'm a bit confused on this point, maybe a different way to load the components? Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like we have the latest version in npm dependencies:

`
"node-requirejs-define": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-requirejs-define/-/node-requirejs-define-1.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-5x7DpGQ/P3PwnYcWKslZcqnmZt8=",
      "requires": {
        "requirejs": "2.3.6"
      }
    },
`